# 2 packages require different versions of Guzzle

Tags: php, composer-php

My application uses 2 packages. Both of them use another package (`guzzle 3`).

Then one of packages has been updated (and I **need** this update) and it started to require different `guzzle` version: `guzzle 4`.
`Guzzle 3` and `guzzle 4` have different APIs.
So I can't update to this version.

Is there any way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ### [Is it possible to use Guzzle 3 and 4 in the same project?](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/faq.html#is-it-possible-to-use-guzzle-3-and-4-in-the-same-project)
>
> Yes, because Guzzle 3 and 4 use different Packagist packages and
>   different namespaces. You simply need to add guzzle/guzzle (Guzzle 3)
>   and guzzlehttp/guzzle (Guzzle 4+) to your project's composer.json
>   file.
>
> ```
> {
>     "require": {
>         "guzzle/guzzle": "3.*",
>         "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "4.*"
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> You might need to use Guzzle 3 and Guzzle 4 in the same project due to
>   a requirement of a legacy application or a dependency that has not yet
>   migrated to Guzzle 4.0.

Comment: Note this solution is specific to Guzzle, which is why I updated your question title. Other situations may not be able to be resolved so easily; that's mostly the responsibility of the package owner when they decide to break backward compatibility.

Comment: There is no need to add Guzzle as dependency if the other packages list it as dependency. Guzzle 4 has not been published under the old package name. If a package needs Guzzle 4, it must require it via the new name. This will be resolved by Composer just fine.